# Custom Event Arguments - Should I use a class member or a new instance?

Tags: c#

I have a callback that is called from a 3rd party com interop, and it's called quite often. (Thousands of times.) I raise an event in one the callback's methods and I was curious if it would be better to use a class member for the event args or create a new instance of the event args class for each event? The event I raise updates the UI.

I am wondering if there is a point in creating another instance for each event when it's going to be called *a lot*.

Using a class member:

```
private ProgressEventArgs m_eventArgs;
public bool ProgressStep(ProgressType eType, string bsMessage, int lProgressPos)
{
    if (ProgressEventStep != null)
    {
        m_eventArgs.Value = lProgressPos;
        ProgressEventStep(this, m_eventArgs);                
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or

```
public bool ProgressStep(ProgressType eType, string bsMessage, int lProgressPos)
{
    if (ProgressEventStep != null)
        ProgressEventStep(this, new ProgressEventArgs(lProgressPos));                    
    return true;
}
```

Which would be preferred? Or does it much matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the constructor for `ProgressEventStep` doesn't do anything unusual there should be very little overhead in creating objects.

Performance aside, since you're reusing the same object in the first scenario you risk getting the wrong event data in a multi-threaded scenario.

Comment: I figured it didn't much matter but it's a question I have had in the back of my head for a while. Thanks!